# Function Postgresl at Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

i have problem with my function at postgresql and call it in laravel code, i have function in different schema, if i generate my function it generate some funtions to but it on different schema.
ex:
i have 3 schema (public, data, references) i have function data.first_function($i int) and refrences.second_function()

`DB::select('SELECT data.first_function(10) as value')`

in this case i'm expect data.first_function generate function references.second_function too. but when im run function references.second_function its cant generate coz that fungsion only read as second_function.

find a solution from my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fully qualified names, construct functions explicitly in the schema for which they are meant, and confirm that the user has the necessary permissions to execute the functions. Try debugging directly in a PostgreSQL client if problems still there.

Try running these commands

```
// Set the search path to include the relevant schemas
DB::statement('SET search_path TO data, references, public');

// Call the first function from the 'data' schema
DB::select('SELECT data.first_function(10) as value');

// Call the second function from the 'references' schema
DB::select('SELECT references.second_function() as value');
```

Hope it's helpful :)